# Need help using powershell to create list items

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, list, powershell, caml-query

I based my code from this [example](http://adicodes.com/copy-or-replace-list-items-in-powershell/) it stated it had the ability to create list items with attachments from existing list items in a new list. I liked this example because I would like to archive old items on my list. I created a CAML Query that would look for items in the list with the "Archived" status. When I tested the query it worked perfectly. Then I inserted it in the code, and I don't think the code recognizes the query. When I run the code it will just make a copy of every list item in the source list, instead of "Archived" items only.

Does anyone know what I can do to get the code recognize the CAML Query and only create the items queried?

Update: both lists are Custom Lists if that changes anything

```
Remove-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -erroraction SilentlyContinue
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -erroraction SilentlyContinue
try
{

    # REQUIRED: URL to source SharePoint site with list
    $srcListSiteUrl = "http://testsrv/sites/home/pre-sales"

    # REQUIRED: Name of source list.
    $SourceListName = "Pre-SalesNew2"

    # REQUIRED: URL to destination SharePoint site with list (can be the same site)
    $dstListSiteUrl = "http://testsrv/sites/home/pre-sales"

    # REQUIRED: Name of destination list.
    $DestinationListName = "ArchivedPreSalesRecords"

    # Finds the source SharePoint site and then appends "/lists/" and the list name to the URL. 
    $sourceListWeb = Get-SPWeb -identity $srcListSiteUrl
    $sourceListUrl = $sourceListWeb.ServerRelativeUrl + "/lists/" + $SourceListName;

    # Finds the destination SharePoint site and then appends "/lists/" and the list name to the URL.    
    $dstListWeb = Get-SPWeb -identity $dstListSiteUrl
    $destinationListUrl = $dstListWeb.ServerRelativeUrl + "/lists/" + $DestinationListName;

    # Finds the list at the URLs stored in the variables
    $SourceList = $sourceListWeb.GetList($sourceListUrl);
    $DestinationList = $dstListWeb.GetList($destinationListUrl);

    $sourceSPListItemCollection = $SourceList.GetItems();
    foreach($srcListItem in $sourceSPListItemCollection)
    {  

        #CAML query
        $camlQuery =
         '<Where>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name="StatusPreSales" />
                    <Value Type="Choice">Archived</Value>
                </Eq>  
        </Where>'
        $spQuery = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
        $spQuery.Query = $camlQuery


            write-host "adding new item"
            $newSPListItem = $DestinationList.AddItem(); 

            foreach($spField in $srcListItem.Fields)
            {
              if ($spField.ReadOnlyField -ne $True -and  $spField.InternalName -ne "Attachments")
              {
                  $newSPListItem[$spField.InternalName] = $srcListItem[$spField.InternalName];
              }
            }
             # Handle Attachments
            foreach($leafName in $srcListItem.Attachments)
              {
                $spFile = $SourceList.ParentWeb.GetFile($srcListItem.Attachments.UrlPrefix + $leafName)
                $newSPListItem.Attachments.Add($leafName, $spFile.OpenBinary());
              }
            $newSPListItem.Update()
    }

}
catch
{
    write-host $_.exception
}
finally
{
    if($sourceListWeb -ne $null){$sourceListWeb.Dispose()}
    if($dstListWeb -ne $null){$dstListWeb.Dispose()}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a CAML query :

```
Remove-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -erroraction SilentlyContinue
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -erroraction SilentlyContinue
try
{

    # REQUIRED: URL to source SharePoint site with list
    $srcListSiteUrl = "http://testsrv/sites/home/pre-sales"

    # REQUIRED: Name of source list.
    $SourceListName = "Pre-SalesNew2"

    # REQUIRED: URL to destination SharePoint site with list (can be the same site)
    $dstListSiteUrl = "http://testsrv/sites/home/pre-sales"

    # REQUIRED: Name of destination list.
    $DestinationListName = "ArchivedPreSalesRecords"

    # Finds the source SharePoint site and then appends "/lists/" and the list name to the URL. 
    $sourceListWeb = Get-SPWeb -identity $srcListSiteUrl
    $sourceListUrl = $sourceListWeb.ServerRelativeUrl + "/lists/" + $SourceListName;

    # Finds the destination SharePoint site and then appends "/lists/" and the list name to the URL.    
    $dstListWeb = Get-SPWeb -identity $dstListSiteUrl
    $destinationListUrl = $dstListWeb.ServerRelativeUrl + "/lists/" + $DestinationListName;

    # Finds the list at the URLs stored in the variables
    $SourceList = $sourceListWeb.GetList($sourceListUrl);
    $DestinationList = $dstListWeb.GetList($destinationListUrl);

    $sourceSPListItemCollection = $SourceList.GetItems();
    foreach($srcListItem in $sourceSPListItemCollection)
    {
```

> $value = $srcListItem["StatusPreSales"];
>        if($value -Eq 'Archived')

```
 {
            write-host "adding new item"
            $newSPListItem = $DestinationList.AddItem(); 

            foreach($spField in $srcListItem.Fields)
            {
              if ($spField.ReadOnlyField -ne $True -and  $spField.InternalName -ne "Attachments")
              {
                  $newSPListItem[$spField.InternalName] = $srcListItem[$spField.InternalName];
              }
            }
             # Handle Attachments
            foreach($leafName in $srcListItem.Attachments)
              {
                $spFile = $SourceList.ParentWeb.GetFile($srcListItem.Attachments.UrlPrefix + $leafName)
                $newSPListItem.Attachments.Add($leafName, $spFile.OpenBinary());
              }
            $newSPListItem.Update()
    }

}}
catch
{
    write-host $_.exception
}
finally
{
    if($sourceListWeb -ne $null){$sourceListWeb.Dispose()}
    if($dstListWeb -ne $null){$dstListWeb.Dispose()}
}
```

Comment: When I run your code all is see is `processing folder PreSalesListContentType
done with folder
processing folder Attachments
done with folder
processing folder Item
done with folder` I was reading through it and it's suppose to create a folder if it doesn't exist, but nothing was created when I ran the code. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You will not need a caml query because you are already in loop and there is no need for a query . Just find the matching value and proceed else skip .